# Problems with a custom pay link shortcode on WooCommerce/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce, payment-gateway

Hello I am trying to create custom payment links for various payment methods. I would like the link to be generated on WooCommerce based on a cart or order total at the checkout page. Here is what I have been trying in my functions php file.

```
function customhaywoo(){
global  $woocommerce, $total, $amount ;
$woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$total = $woocommerce->cart->get_total();
$amount = $woocommerce->cart->total;
if ( ! $amount ) {
    return;
}
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "href" => 'https://venmo.com/hayden-55?txn=pay&amount=',
    esc_attr( wp_kses_post( $amount ) ),
   ), $atts));
return '<a href="'.$href.'">'.$content.'</a>';
}
add_shortcode ('haywoo','customhaywoo');
```

I have tried other combinations as well however as you can probably tell I have absolutely no experience and have no idea what I am doing. I got the idea of what I should include in the code from "checkout with Venmo" by the African boss plugin. I would just use the plugin however I need this for a few other Payment methods. For many of the Payment methods you can just add the number amount at the end of the url and it will automatically have the amount inserted into the payment method. Basically I somehow need to get the cart or order total to appear at the end of a link without the currency symbol.

Edit- I tried this for displaying on the thank you page. This just shows up as nothing at all. not even the [haywoo]. Any help on this would be awesome!

```html
function customhaywoo()
 {
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$total = $order->get_total();
$order_total = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $order->get_total()) );
if (!$order_total) {
return; 
    }
ob_start();
$pay_link = 'https://venmo.com/hayden-595?txn=pay&amount='.$order_total;

$payment_text = __('Click here to pay '.$order_total, 'text_domain'); 
    
echo  '<a href="' . $pay_link . '">' . $payment_text . '</a>';

$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $contents; '<a href="'.$href.'">'.$content.'</a>';
}
add_shortcode('haywoo', 'customhaywoo');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the shortcode to output the payment link with the total amount of cart then try out below edited code.

```
function customhaywoo()
{
    global  $woocommerce, $total, $amount;
    $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $total_amount = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );
    if (!$total_amount) {
        return;
    }
    ob_start();
    $pay_link = 'https://venmo.com/hayden-55?txn=pay&amount='.$total_amount;

    $payment_text = __('Click here to pay '.$total_amount, 'text_domain'); 
    
    echo  '<a href="' . $pay_link . '">' . $payment_text . '</a>';

    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $contents;
}
add_shortcode('haywoo', 'customhaywoo');
```

I Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this resulted in crashing my site to the page saying "There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions." I was able to put the code into my functions.php in my theme however I then tried exiting the theme file functions.php it resulted in that error page.

Comment: got it to work, however it inputs 360.10 instead of 10.00. I believe it is adding all the placed order total amounts from the customer together or its adding all the Products available in the store together and it caused a critical error on my site on the backend (wordpress admin)

Comment: I figure its easier to just use it by the order i.d on the thank you page. how would I do that?

Comment: You can hook into thankyou page using woocommerce_thankyou hook. Then extract the total amount from order object.  add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function( $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

$order_total = $order->get_total();
});

Comment: How would I do that with the link ? Would you mind putting the code I could copy and paste including the venmo link? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also where would I put that code in the theme functions.php file or somewhere else? Also The link will be different for each payment method , I don’t want it to be on all the thank you page for all orders , that’s why I want the shortcode so I can add it to the payment methods instructions that show on the thank you page if payment method is selected. Hope that made sense.